# Angular 6 Material Menu Building,

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Due to the complexity of the company I work for, we have a number of departments and a number of roles within each department. Therefore using the typical roles of admin, staff and user simply won't cut it. Therefore I am using bit manipulation to assign a value to each department/role in  order to prevent complicated user access control strings (for routes and menus).

I have the code below, but no matter what I do, I cannot get the children of the menu item to be visible or not depending upon the UAC value.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface BadgeItem {
    type: string;
    value: string;
}
export interface Saperator {
    name: string;
    type ? : string;
}
export interface ChildrenItems {
    state: string;
    name: string;
    type ? : string;
}

export interface Menu {
    state: string;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    icon: string;
    badge ? : BadgeItem[];
    saperator ? : Saperator[];
    children ? : ChildrenItems[];
}

const MENUITEMS = [
    {
        state: '',
        name: 'Personal',
        type: 'saperator',
        icon: 'av_timer'
    },
    {
        state: 'dashboards',
        name: 'Dashboards',
        type: 'sub',
        icon: 'av_timer',
        children: [
            { state: 'dashboard1', name: 'Dashboard 1', UAC: 0 },
            { state: 'dashboard2', name: 'Dashboard 2', UAC: 128 },
        ]
    },
    {
        state: 'apps',
        name: 'Apps',
        type: 'sub',
        icon: 'apps',
        children: [
            { state: 'calendar', name: 'Calendar' },
            { state: 'messages', name: 'Mail box' },
            { state: 'chat', name: 'Chat' },
            { state: 'taskboard', name: 'Taskboard' }
        ],
        UAC: 256
    },
    {
        state: '',
        name: 'Forms, Table & Widgets',
        type: 'saperator',
        icon: 'av_timer'
    }, {
        state: 'datatables',
        name: 'Data Tables',
        type: 'sub',
        icon: 'border_all',

        children: [
            { state: 'basicdatatable', name: 'Basic Data Table' },
            { state: 'filter', name: 'Filterable' },
            { state: 'editing', name: 'Editing' },
        ]
    }, {
        state: 'pages',
        name: 'Pages',
        type: 'sub',
        icon: 'content_copy',

        children: [
            { state: 'icons', name: 'Material Icons' },
            { state: 'timeline', name: 'Timeline' },
            { state: 'invoice', name: 'Invoice' },
            { state: 'pricing', name: 'Pricing' },
            { state: 'helper', name: 'Helper Classes' }
        ]
    }

];

@Injectable()

export class MenuItems {

    getMenuitem(): Menu[] {

        // Get the JSON form of the stored user object
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

        // If the user has logged in, then this user object will be non null
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) 
        {
            var filtered_MENUITEMS = MENUITEMS.filter(obj => {

                let parentUAC: boolean = true;

                // Or are we using a UAC value instead.
                if(obj.UAC)
                {
                    // Current User UAC could be 256, using bit manipulation for the number of departments and roles.
                    parentUAC = ((obj.UAC & currentUser.UAC) > 0) ? true : false;
                } 

                // We are going to show the parent, now check the children.
                if( (parentUAC == true) && (obj.children) )
                {
                    // Need code in here to check for children of the menu item and removing if it's not meant to be visible.
                }

                return parentUAC;
            });

            return filtered_MENUITEMS;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return MENUITEMS;
        }

    }

}
```

I think the issue that I'm getting confused with, is that I'm trying to remove the sub-menu or child-menu item from the filtered OBJ whereas it should be removed from the main menu object.

I'm new to Angular so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I eventually ended up using, just in case it is helpful to anyone in the future.

```
@Injectable()

export class MenuItems {

    getMenuitem(): Menu[] {

        // Set the default UAC.
        let UAC: number = 0;

        // Get the JSON form of the stored user object
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

        // If the user has logged in, then this user object will be non null
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) 
        {
            // Overwrite the default UAC with the current users one.
            UAC = currentUser.UAC;
        }

        MENUITEMS.forEach(function(v, i){

                        // If there's a UAC, test it.
                        if( (v.UAC) && ( (v.UAC & UAC) != v.UAC))
                                MENUITEMS.splice(i, 1);

                        // If the menu item has children.
                        if(v.children)
                        {
                                let children: any = v.children;

                                children.forEach(function(w, j){

                                        // If a child has a UAC value, check it!
                                        if( (w.UAC) && ( (w.UAC & UAC) == w.UAC))
                                                MENUITEMS[i].children.splice(j, 1);
                                });

                        }
        })

        // Return the MENUITEMS.
        return MENUITEMS;
    }
}
```

This is how the code currently stands, no doubt it will be tweaked as the project progresses.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your default `parentUAC` to false

```
let parentUAC: boolean = false;
```

I then changed your `parentUAC` comparison to this.

```
 parentUAC = obj.UAC == currentUser.UAC ? true : false;
```

I then used the view to control if the `children` items are displayed.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu3">Menu With UAC 256</button>
<mat-menu #menu3="matMenu">
    <div *ngFor="let item of getMenuitem({token:'1234', UAC:'256'})">
      <button *ngIf="!item.children" mat-menu-item>{{item.name}}</button>
      <button *ngIf="item.children" mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="submenu">{{item.name}}</button>
      <mat-menu #submenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let subItem of item.children">{{subItem.name}}</button>
      </mat-menu>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

Please see `Menu With UAC 256` in revised stackblitz.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v43gjg?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.ts

Comment: Sorry bout that. CurrentUser is set in local storage & contains some basic information about the user currently logged on, one part of that information is the UAC value.

The value, UAC, comes from the database and the Laravel backend API and restricts users to certain routes and rather than show all menu items to everyone, only for some to work & for others not to, I wanted to only show the menu items applicable to that particular UAC.

This can either be the whole menu section such as Pages or individual menu entries within a menu section. It is the latter that I'm struggling with.

Comment: Please see revised answer.

Comment: Thank you Marshal for the revised answer. Whilst that does what it says on the tin, the token is coming from the current user and the UAC value is coded for each individual group or item of a group.

So imagine that we have three departments within a company and you only want certain people to see the departments they need to, as opposed to all. You couldn't set a single UAC in the template, but it would have to be done within the menu items themselves.

When a user logs in, the currentUser, they are assigned a UAC which restricts what they see and where they can go.